# visual basic express 2010 at school

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Can I use, legally and without paying any money, Visual Basic Express 2010 to teach programming at school ? I need to install it on 20 PCs. If it is possible, how do I handle the product registration ? Do I need a different code, and hence Microsoft account, for each PC or can I use the same one on all machines ? I've seen that pratically I can register with the same code different PCs but I need to be sure that everything I do at school is 100% legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft actually gives Visual Basic Express Free to students for a year and it's free to download as well. The website is called [**DreamSpark**](https://www.dreamspark.com/) and this is a link to [**Visual Basic Express 2010**](https://www.dreamspark.com/Product/Product.aspx?productid=32). Hope This helps.

Comment: Yes, nice. But it looks like it's free for a student while it requires a, small, annual fee for institutions. I can't understand if I can legally install it simply with my personal account on all machines.